# Getting Segmentation fault while parsing a text file

Tags: c, linux

I am doing some simple logic to parse a comma separated text file. I am getting segmentation error at exactly in the most outer while loop as i am giving sz+1. but instead sz+1 i have used sizeof(str1) then i am getting out of it smoothly but the results are not capturing accurately. I am getting segmentation fault core dumped error at the end after completing total iterations..
please any one help me...

```
    int main()
      {
        char *str1;
        unsigned char user_id[10]="",pwd[10]="",name[75]="",frm_dt[15]="", to_dt[15]="", ntry_dt[15]="",lim_amt[15]="",act_flag[5]="";
            char *ptr;
            char *temp;
            int i=1,t,rc=0,sz=0;
            char delims[]=",";
            char filename[100] = "/home/erpdirect/Desktop/billcollectors.txt";
            FILE *fp;
            temp = (char*)malloc(strlen(ptr)+1);
            rc=0;
            fp= fopen("/home/erpdirect/Desktop/billcollectors.txt","r");
            if (fp == NULL)
            {
                printf("No such file");
                //return 1;

            }
            fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
            sz = ftell(fp);
            fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
            printf("Size of File : %d \n",sz);
            printf("\nLoop is in file pointer\n");
            str1 =(char*)malloc(sz*sizeof(char));
            while(fgets(str1,sz+1,fp) !=NULL)
            {

                printf("\n");

                ptr=strtok(str1,delims);
                //printf("\nPoints to >>>>>>>>>  %s",ptr);
                while(ptr != NULL)
                {
                    i=1;
                    memset(user_id,0,sizeof(user_id));
                    memset(name,0,sizeof(name));
                    memset(pwd,0,sizeof(pwd));
                    memset(frm_dt,0,sizeof(frm_dt));
                    memset(to_dt,0,sizeof(to_dt));
                    memset(lim_amt,0,sizeof(lim_amt));
                    memset(ntry_dt,0,sizeof(ntry_dt));
                    memset(act_flag,0,sizeof(act_flag));

                    while(ptr!=NULL && i<=16)
                    {
                        strcpy(temp, ptr);

                        printf("\nTemp values are : %s",temp);
                        ptr = strtok(NULL,delims);
                        //printf("\nPoints to >>>>>>>>>  %s",ptr);
                        switch(i)
                        {
                            case 1: strcpy(user_id,temp);
                                printf("\nUSER ID: %s",user_id);
                                    break;//insert into categoryId  

                            case 2: strcpy(pwd,temp);   
                                printf("\nPASSWORD: %s",pwd);   break;

                            case 3: strcpy(name,temp);
                                printf("\nName: %s",name);      break; 

                            case 4: strcpy(frm_dt,temp);    
                                printf("\nFROM DATE: %s",frm_dt);   break;

                            case 5: strcpy(to_dt,temp);     
                                printf("\nTO DATE: %s",to_dt);      break;

                            case 6: strcpy(lim_amt,temp);       
                                printf("\nLIMIT Amt: %s",lim_amt);  break;

                            case 7: strcpy(ntry_dt,temp);       
                                printf("\nEntry Date: %s",ntry_dt);     break;

                            case 8: strcpy(act_flag,temp);      
                                printf("\nActive flag: %s",act_flag);           break;

                            default:break;

                        }//switch

                        i++;    
                    }//while

                }//while

            }//while 

            free(str1);
            free(temp);  

            fclose(fp);

            return SUCCESS;
        }
```

Comment: Unless you've omitted some code, I'm surprised 'temp = (char*)malloc(strlen(ptr)+1);' isn't crashing it, since ptr is not allocated. Your fgets is trying to read more than the entire file too, as 'sz' holds the entire size.

Comment: This is what Valgrind is for, by the way. Though in this case, any debugger would do.

Answer (score 2):

Use a debugger. After adding in some `#include`s, and changing `SUCCESS` to `EXIT_SUCCESS`, here is what GDB gives:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/test 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a00 in main () at test.c:14
14                  temp = (char*)malloc(strlen(ptr)+1);
```

Now, you can use the debugger to inspect your variables. Let's look at `ptr`:

```
(gdb) p ptr
$1 = 0x0
```

Calling `strlen` on `NULL` is, of course, not allowed. When you look at the actual program source, you can see that you failed to initialize ptr before using it (and in this case, the initial value it just happened to get was 0).

Comment: @itsnikki: I'm not sure what you initialized it with (you haven't posted updated code, and my mind-reading skills are a little rusty), but you should be able to use the debugger to find out where its crashing now.

Comment: char *ptr = ""; but this might  not be the problem.. I am getting in while loop of fgets function...

Comment: @itsnikki: Well, take a moment to learn how to use whatever debugger you have available, and then you can use it to find out whats wrong with your program.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you call `strlen(ptr)`, the `ptr` pointer is uninitialised, and you invoke undefined behaviour:

```
/* there is random garbage in ptr, instead of a 
 * valid address to a nul-terminated string
 */
temp = (char*) malloc(strlen(ptr)+1);
```

Also note that casting void pointers on the right side of an assignment (or particularly the result of `malloc`) is unnecessary in C, unlike in C++.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Yes, actually, it is causing the segfault, at least when I run the program here.